# Finding repeater control in class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, foreach, repeater

Am trying to find a repeater control in a class and i don't know where I have done mistake.

In my ASPX page i have repeater which contains two image buttons, and at the page load am calling a method which I have defined in the class.

this is my class page,

```
 public class Authorization
 {
    public Authorization()
    {
    }
    public void ChangeControlStatus(ControlCollection PageControls, int Role_id)
    {
    using (EHSIMSDataContext db = new EHSIMSDataContext())
    {
        var Role_Assigned = (from auth in db.AUTHORISATIONs
                             where auth.ROLE_ID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Role_id)) && auth.PAGE_ACCESS.Equals(1)
                             select auth);

        foreach (Control ctrl in PageControls)
        {
            string ControlName = (ctrl.GetType()).Name;
            switch (ControlName)
            {
                case "ImageButton":
                    ImageButton imgbut = (ImageButton)ctrl;
                    {
                        foreach (var role in Role_Assigned)
                        {
                            if(role.ADD_ACCESS == false)
                                if(imgbut.ID.Equals("BtnAdd"))
                                    imgbut.Enabled = false;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "Repeater":
                    Repeater rep = (Repeater)ctrl;

                    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rep.Items)
                    {
                        ImageButton img_but = item.FindControl("lnkEdit") as ImageButton;
                              if (role.EDIT_ACCESS == false)
                                if (img_but.ID.Equals("lnkEdit"))
                                    img_but.Enabled = false;            
                    }
                    break;


            }
            ChangeControlStatus(ctrl.Controls, Role_id);
        }

    }
}
```

} 
 This is what i have done in the ASPX page,

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Authorization assign_auth = new Authorization();
    assign_auth.ChangeControlStatus(Page.Controls, Roleid);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       -----
```

Now,am passing all the controls to the method "ChangeControlStatus"
since am having image button inside a repeater the foreach in the method above doesn't work,but its finding the 'Repeater' control.
What should i do to find the control in the method?

Additional Message.
So,to say simple in our project we have many users with different roles,based on the roles i want to enable/disable or the controls.
I cant do this in each and every page of our project since there are many controls and many pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Repeater rpt = (Repeater)Page.FindControl("rptr");

        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)rpt.FindControl("lnkEdit");

        if (role.EDIT_ACCESS == false)
                imgBtn.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: @LearningToCode are you sure you add a control with this id **lnkEdit**

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching recursively:

```
public static T FindControl<T>(string id, Control rootControl) where T : Control {
  if (rootControl == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("rootControl");

  var controls = new Stack<Control>();
  controls.Push(rootControl);
  while (controls.Count > 0) {
    var currentControl = controls.Pop();
    var typedControl = currentControl as T;
    if (typedControl != null && string.Compare(typedControl.ID, id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
      return typedControl;

    foreach (Control childControl in currentControl.Controls) {
      controls.Push(childControl);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Invocation (in Page context):

```
var repeater = FindControl<Repeater>("rptr", Page);
foreach(RepeaterItem item in repeater.Items) {
    var imgBtn = FindControl<ImageButton>("lnkEdit", item);
}
```

Comment: Page.FindControl is searching only in direct children collection - so if you have panel on your page and inside that panel you have repeater, you can find panel, but not the repeater. This code is performing deep-first search. At first root container is added to the stack. Then first item is retrieved from stack, if it is our control we return it, otherwise we add children of this control to the stack and continue with next item that is on top of the stack. And if we found nothing it returns null.

Comment: but am able to find the repeater,its the control inside the repeater that am not able to find.Correct me if have wrongly understood.

Comment: The same logic applies there - repeater.FindControl() is searching only direct children controls of repeater - which are controls of type "RepeaterItem", so you can't find image button by doing top-level search only. Btw. code I've posted is searching only for first image button in repeater, changing to find them all.

Comment: sorry the only thing i can get is are you telling to use a helper method?am just a beginner,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Got it clear...!Thank you all for your replies...
Instead of calling the function at page load event,am now calling it at repeater_item data bound,and passing the RepeaterItemEventArgs.
here is what i have done,

```
protected void rptrdepartment_databound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
    {
        Authorization assign_auth = new Authorization();
        int Roleid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Roleid"]);
        assign_auth.ChangeControlStatus(Page.Controls, Roleid, "Approval Path", e);
    }
}
```

and in the method i have done this,

```
 public void ChangeControlStatus(ControlCollection PageControls, int Role_id,string Submenu_Name,RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
 foreach (Control ctrl in PageControls)
        {

            string ControlName = (ctrl.GetType()).Name;
            switch (ControlName)
            {
                case "ImageButton":
                    ImageButton imgbut = (ImageButton)ctrl;
                    ImageButton img_but_delte = e.Item.FindControl("lnkDelete") as ImageButton;
                    ImageButton img_but_edit = e.Item.FindControl("lnkEdit") as ImageButton;
                    {

                        foreach (var role in Role_Assigned)
                        {
                            if(role.ADD_ACCESS == false)
                                if (imgbut.ID.Equals("btnAdd"))
                                    imgbut.Enabled = false;

                            if (role.DELETE_ACCESS == false)
                                    img_but_delte.Enabled = false;

                            if (imgbut.ID.Equals("btnlogout"))
                                    img_but_edit.Enabled = false;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            }
            ChangeControlStatus(ctrl.Controls, Role_id,Submenu_Name,e);
        }
    }
```